# No function matches the given name and argument types you might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, psycopg2

The following statement in the code gives me an error:

```
cur.execute("
   update %s as A
   set fm = foo.fm
   from (
      select src_id as id, agg_bit_or(fm) as fm
      from %s, %s where dst_id = id
      group by src_id) as foo
   where A.id = foo.id" %(tmp_table, edge_table, vertex_table))
```

`agg_bit_or()` is a user defined aggregate function in Postgres defined as:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE agg_bit_or(bit[])
(
    sfunc = bit_or,
    stype = bit[]   
);
```

The error message is:

```
File "radius.py", line 47, in update_bitstring
cur.execute("update %s as A set fm = foo.fm from (select src_id as id, agg_b
it_or(fm)  from %s, %s where dst_id = id group by src_id) as foo where A.id = fo
o.id" %(tmp_table, edge_table, vertex_table))

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: function agg_bit_or(integer[]) does not exist
LINE 1: ...v as A set fm = foo.fm from (select src_id as id, agg_bit_or...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: We would need the table definiton, in particular the *exact* data type of `fm`. Also: What do you get for `SHOW search_path`? And in which schema was `agg_bit_or(bit[])` created?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: function agg_bit_or(**integer[]**) does not exist

While your aggregate function is defined:

> CREATE AGGREGATE agg_bit_or(**bit[]**)

Bold emphasis mine. You need compatible types to begin with.